# Convert .width() in px to % in jQuery for Bootstrap's appended labels while fluid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, math, units-of-measurement

I currently have:

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.span-fix').each(function(){ /* Do this for each extended input */
        var wide = $(this).width(), /* create a variable that holds the width of the form */
            label = $(this).prev('.add-on').width(); /* create another variable that holds the width of the previous label */
        $(this).width( wide - label ); /* subtract the label width from the input width and apply it in px */
    });
});
```

html

```
<div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on">Location</span>
    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tbLocation" type="text" id="tbLocation" class="span12 span-fix" placeholder="Location" style="width: 97.04668304668304%; ">
</div>
```

Fiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/SuguM/

However, this applies the new width in `px`, and I'm using a fluid layout and need this to be a percent again.

Is there a way to convert the `px` applied to a `%`?

Comment: look at outerWidth, width doesn't account for borders and such (IIRC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you omit the padding in your calcul. I think this code help you.

**EDIT :**

This is the code for firefox :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.span-fix').each(function(){ /* Do this for each extended input */
        var label = $(this).prev('.add-on').outerWidth();
        /* create another variable that holds the width of the previous label */
        $(this).width( (1-(label + $(this).outerWidth() - $(this).width())/$(this).parent().width()) *100 + "%" );
    });
});
```

And this is the code for chrome :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.span-fix').each(function(){ /* Do this for each extended input */
        var label = $(this).prev('.add-on').outerWidth(); 
        /* create another variable that holds the width of the previous label */
        $(this).css("width", (1-(label)/$(this).parent().width()) *100 + "%" );
    });
});​
```

For chrome you must set the property css if you use the width method when you check the width css property, the property value is not equel to the value calculated.

There is an example on jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/vHCFm/).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/vHCFm/3/) there is a jsFiddle with the two implementation. Now you just need to detect the browser.

Comment: this seems close too! though it doesn't work completely.. even in your fiddle!

Comment: whichi navigator are you using ? I assume there is a little marge on the tight. Another question. Do you want the same thing for the height ?

Comment: What do you mean by navigator? guessing browser? (chrome for mac) yes margin on the right :( nope! don't need height :)

Comment: Ok you are right on chrome it doesn't work. Welcome in the web development -_-"

Comment: The problems to the calcul of the width. In chrome the real width of the div is not equal to the css property and for firefox it is.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks :) This should seriously be added to bootstrap, it solves the issue of having appended labels for fluid layouts! YAY!

Answer (score 0):

This takes the parent's width and just calculates the percentage.

```
$(this).width((wide - label)/$(this).parent().width()*100+'%');
```

Comment: Ok, so this seems like it is close.. This leaves me with the same size (width) of an input form as if I didn't have any jquery at all though.. (almost as if I've lost the first half of the code.

Comment: @Reuben That is odd I'm having a hard time visualizing your HTML so I can't tell you what exactly is going on.  You could log the values of the parent, wide-lable, and the final percentage to see if they make sense.  Or if they don't then that might tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: @Reuben here is a jsfiddle of my tests http://jsfiddle.net/CC3pm/. As far as I can tell the width in this case is going from ~98% to ~78%.  This is based on me giving the the arbitrary width of 300 to the containing div.  It is possible that if the width of the containing div is large enough it might make it look like there is no change.

Comment: I'm using the fluid scaffolding layout of twitter's bootstrap if that helps any?

Comment: @Reuben is this what your looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/SuguM/5/?  I'm not sure why you need it be a percentage though.  Because you are calculating on the fly it means after the page loads you are getting the width based on the size of the page so I'm not sure how using a percentage helps.  Also if you resize it later the fact that the label's width is given in pixels means you would still have to recalculate it every time.

Comment: When I look at that (chrome on mac) the form field is still outside the black border, it should fit within just that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on an earlier [post](http://yckart.com/jquery-get-elements-percentage/) by me.

```
var getPercent = function(elem) {
    var elemName = elem.attr("id"),
        width = elem.width(),
        parentWidth = elem.offsetParent().width(),
        percent = Math.round(100 * width / parentWidth);
    return percent;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This calculates the percentage with the entire document:

```
$(this).width((wide - label) * 100 / $(document).width()+'%');
```

Comment: I'm not really looking for the % of the doc :/