# Dynamically space out divs base don size of parent

Tags: jquery, html, spacing

I have a container div. Inside that container div are a number of smaller divs that I would like to space out the width of the parent div while adding a gap between each. The number of inner divs will change.

I'm using this formula **(containerWidth-(numberOfBars*gap))/numberOfBars** to figure out each bar's space and then trying jquery to modify the css dynamically.

I can't get the width to change or get them to space out.

A fiddle is attached.

http://jsfiddle.net/MjrMq/

Thank you!

Comment: You have a lot of missing variables in your fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/); I think it suits this situation quite well. When `true` is passed, it will take the outer width of a container, including the margin. Therefore, when you have an item of width `0`, and take the outer width, it will be only the padding/margin/border you don't want included in the width.

Next, I played with your logic a bit. I took the total width of each bar instead of the inner width, then used the outer width to get the inner width from it. (That is, `Container width / n -> Outer Width; Subtract padding -> Inner Width`.)

Last thing I want to note before sharing the updated fiddle is: Please, please, **please**, in the future, test your fiddle first. You had created `bar` and `container` variables, neither of which was defined. Nor had you used `$(document).ready(...)` or anything similar.

First, I set your `width` to `0` (to get proper outer width). Then I calculated the width, as such:

```
var barOuterWidth = Math.floor(containerWidth / n);
var barInnerWidth = barOuterWidth - $(".bar").outerWidth(true);
```

Lastly, I used `'width': barInnerWidth,` to set the width.

The result is [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DLEpU/). Notice there is a margin gap on the right; I'm sure you can find a way to alleviate this. (`i == n - 1` or whatnot.)

Comment: If I can say one thing careful with outerWidth the returned value are different with the browser. I tested this afternoon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362376/convert-width-in-px-to-in-jquery-for-bootstraps-appended-labels-while-flui/12373979

Comment: @CharlesJourdan I don't have other browsers handy to check, but this is always something to worry about with dimensions. Good catch.